# How to Inject session bean in custom spring security login success handler

Tags: spring, session, authentication, spring-security

i'm unable to inject a spring session bean in my custom success handler:

```
@Component
public class CustomSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Resource
    private SessionController sessionController;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        sessionController.setUtenteOnline();
    }
```

that return a null pointer exception on sessionController.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't you mean to use @Autowire?

Comment: it doesn't work also with @Autowired

Comment: What do you mean by a "spring session bean"?

Comment: A Scope("session") bean managed by spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success handler is probably a singleton so you can only inject singletons into it reliably. You can solve this problem using [scoped dependencies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection). Basically, it involves Spring injecting a singleton dynamic proxy that manages fetching the real bean from session scope and delegating calls to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but at this moment i haven't time to test your solution. I have do a workoround but i'm sure I will need again this feature.